# Why am I getting a segmentation fault on INT 0x10 under Linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, bios

I am running this from a bash shell in Ubuntu. I am trying to learn about OS dev and wanted to run a simple ISR that prints to the teletype terminal.

**print_h.asm**

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov ah , 0x0e
    mov al , 'H'
    int 0x10

    jmp $ ; Jump to the current address ( i.e. forever ) .
```

**Build**

```
nasm print_h.asm -f elf64 -o print_h.o
ld print_h.o -o print_h
```

**Run**

```
./print_h
```

Output:

`Segmentation fault`

Comment: It seems you tried to run that in 64-bit user-space under a modern OS (Linux).  Not under a legacy IBM-PC BIOS that has an `int 0x10` handler!  Linux requires Linux programs to make Linux system calls, not bypass the kernel and talk to the BIOS.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! The code above was taken from a section on Boot Sector Programming (in16-bit Real Mode) Thank you

Comment: If I ran this as `sudo`, would that take me from user-space into kernal-space, and allow me to do this?

Comment: The `root` *user* is still user-space (ring 3, or in formal x86 terminology CPL = 3, Current Privilege Level).  They can't accidentally execute [`invd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/invd) and hose the machine by discarding cache contents without write-back.  (Or other privileged instructions).  But no, even if you put this in a *kernel module*, it still wouldn't work.  Linux takes over all the RAM when it boots, overwriting the BIOS, and its IDT entry for interrupt number 0x10 doesn't point to a handler that looks at AH for a call number.

Comment: @Thomas There is no way you can have a Linux program use these BIOS routines and have it work.  The BIOS routines are written for real mode and expect the hardware to be set up in the way the BIOS expects it.  This is no longer the case when Linux runs, so even if you somehow manage to enter real mode (or Virtual 8086 mode) and have permission to access the hardware, it still won't work as expected.  Do not try to use BIOS interfaces outside of real mode.

Comment: Legacy IBM-PC stuff is completely unusable after booting Linux.  (Or even after switching to protected mode from a DOS program, BTW.)  See also [How does the BIOS distinguish Interrupt(08h-12h) from INT instructions, vs. actual exceptions inside the CPU?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24552) for some DOS and early-PC history about how IBM used those interrupt numbers that Intel marked as reserved in the 8086 manual.  `int 0x10` is the same interrupt number that x87 FPU exceptions use, if unmasked.

Comment: Just a side note 32-bit Linux does have the vm86() function. And there is a Kernel patch for the x86-64 processors that puts one of the processors in real mode and then has an interface to run real mode code. Of course one would have to assume that there is a legacy BIOS on the machine.