# NASM x86_64 Clearing screen, changing color and cursor position wont set

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I have this project that I am busy with and have gotten the biggest part of it out of the way

However, this last part I just can't get right. Every time when I try something out from a different post it would crash.

I have tried this for the clearing screen for example

```
    mov al, 00h
    mov bh, 0
    mov bh, 0
    mov ah, 2
    int 10h
```

I have tried this for changing the color of the screen to white on blue

```
    mov ah, 09h
    mov cx, 1000h
    mov al, 20h
    mov bl, 17  ; This is Blue & White.
```

And of course the cursor positioning doesn't work either

```
    mov  ah, 2  
    mov  bh, 0  
    mov  dl, 10  
    mov  dh, 0  
    int  10h
```

I just don't know what to do at this point
I am writing in NASM x86_64 by the way
Don't think I should post my assignment online because I don't want to get in issues with my university

edit: added an example of a curser code that didn't work

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?  `int 10h` is a BIOS entry point.  Unless you have a custom operating system providing the same interface, this is not going to work in protected or long mode.

Comment: See comments and duplicates on [Why am I getting a segmentation fault on INT 0x10 under Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72512123) - BIOS calls only work in real mode in a bootloader, or under DOS.  Not under any proper OS that takes over the machine, and not even after switching to protected mode yourself from DOS or a bootloader.

Comment: @fuz I'm programming for Windows 64, turning the asm to an exe with
`nasm -fwin32 main.asm`
`gcc main.obj -o main.exe`
and I then execute the exe with the cmd

Comment: @BradStanton Then you cannot use this interface.  Find out what the corresponding Win32 interface is and use that.  It's probably some function in the Win32 API.